# Take out common variables using Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a formlua in DNF form, say:

```
abcx + abcy + abz
```

Is there any way to take out the common variables, to get the follwing formula:

```
ab (cx + cy + z)
```

A followup question, can it be done recursively, like

```
ab ( c(x+y) + z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.. Here's one way:

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c, x, y, z = Ints('a b c x y z')
print simplify(a*b*c*x + a*b*c*y + a*b*z, hoist_mul=True)
```

This prints:

```
a*b*(c*(x + y) + z)
```

which is exactly what you're looking for.

And for your next question, how did I find about `hoist_cmul=True` argument? Simply run:

```
help_simplify()
```

at your Python prompt, and it'll list you all the options `simplify` takes.

Note that you should in general not count on what the simplifier will give you. It's mostly heuristic driven, and in the presence of other terms what you get may not match what you expected. (It'll of course still be an equivalent expression.) There's no notion of "simplest" when it comes to arithmetic expressions, and what you consider simple and what z3 considers simple may not necessarily match.